# How to prevent IE from showing "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts ..." message when opening just a text file?

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi

In my software I need to open a plain text file for viewing only. I chose to use a default web browser to do that since it is most certainly available on any system. (Note that I can't use Notepad because of the "*for viewing only*" restriction.)

So to do that I do the following:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", TextFilePath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This works great on all web browsers, except, ... (you guessed it) IE. That shows this message:

> "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or
>   ActiveX controls"

[image]

The text file obviously doesn't have any scripts or Active X controls. It's just a `.txt` file! But understandably this message worries some users that think that my program tries to run something "bad" on their computer.

So I'm curious, if there a way to prevent this dumb message without modifying any global IE settings?

Comment: How did you get ShellExecute to run IE rather than notepad?  The "open" verb would default to notepad for a .txt file, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why would you need to open a `.txt` file in a **web browser**? I'd incorporate a viewing method of it in the application (since you can pretty easily write code to get the content of said `.txt` file as a `string` if you can write it to a `.txt` file, or make it into an `HTML` page.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Really. Hmm. I just supplied the path to a .txt file in my `TextFilePath` variable and it opened it in IE. I believe that "edit" would open it in Notepad.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE: True. I should admit that I was taking a shortcut.

Comment: That seems odd - what happens if you double-click a text file in Explorer?  Or right-click it and select "Open"?  (And is the behaviour different for this particular text file than for an arbitrary text file?)

Comment: Given "all web browsers, except" it sounds like they're trying all programs that *can* open text files, just to be safe in the case that someone didn't associate `.txt` with a text editor for some reason...

Comment: @HarryJohnston: If I double-click it, the file will be opened in a Notepad.

Comment: And right-click "Open"?

Comment: @andlabs: he means that if (for example) the default browser is Firefox, it opens successfully in Firefox but that if the default browser is IE it opens but displays the error message.  It isn't opening in *both* Firefox *and* IE *and* Chrome. :-)

Comment: Also, what happens if you type `start iexplore c:\path\to\file.txt` at the command line?  (IE displays the text file happily on my home machine, but I'm still running Vista so it's IE9.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston that's not what I meant either but his "What?" reply shows that I was wrong anyway; carry on ^^'

Comment: @HarryJohnston: If I run `iexplore "c:\path\to\file.txt"`it opens IE with the exact same warning. What is also interesting is that it happens in IE11 on Windows 7 but it doesn't happen anymore when I try it on my Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should execute the following steps:

1. Go to internet options
2. Tab "advanced"
3. Scroll down to Security
4. Check mark "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: This works, but inconvenient that it has to be done once per-user;  But why does IE pop up this warning for files and webpages that do not contain any scripts or active content?